# "Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate" error when Building Arch Linux Package

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, makepkg

I'm trying to build an Arch Linux package for some icon theme, so I used this PKGBUILD file :

```
pkgname=masalla
pkgver=1.1
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="A flat design icon theme by Hayder Majid"
arch=('any')
url="https://github.com/masalla-art/masalla-icon-theme"
license=('GPL3')
makedepends=('git')
conflicts=('masalla-icon-theme-git' 'masalla-icon-theme' 'masalla')
source=("${url}/releases/download/${pkgver}/${pkgname}_${pkgver}.tar.xz")
md5sums=('8c11f0fd04abc6c7f9086f7275d939be')

package() {
  cd $srcdir
  install -d -m 755 ${pkgdir}/usr/share/icons
  cp -r ${srcdir}/${pkgname}_${pkgver}/masalla ${pkgdir}/usr/share/icons
  cp -r ${srcdir}/${pkgname}_${pkgver}/masalla-dark ${pkgdir}/usr/share/icons

}
```

and the compiling process is work fine, but when i installing it, i got this message :

```
(1/2) Updating icon theme caches...
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
error: command failed to execute correctly
(2/2) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
```

so,what i missed in my `PKGBUILD` file, and what should i change to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error message, it is one of [pacman's hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Hooks).

It was introduced in an update to systemd, and is essentially explained by [Lennart here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/stateless.html):

> A new condition ConditionNeedsUpdate= has been added. With this
>   mechanism it is possible to conditionalize execution of services
>   depending on whether /usr is newer than /etc or /var. The idea is that
>   various services that need to be added into the boot process on
>   upgrades make use of this to not delay boot-ups on normal boots, but
>   run as necessary should /usr have been update since the last boot.
>   This is implemented based on the mtime timestamp of the /usr: if the
>   OS has been updated the packaging software should touch the directory,
>   thus informing all instances that an upgrade of /etc and /var might be
>   necessary.

In essence, the hook ensures that those services that need to be run on boot if `/usr` has been updated will be run. You can read more in `man 5 systemd.unit`

Comment: Ok, so that's how it's used, but what does it mean if you get this message during an install? Does it mean there will be some additional calls run during the next boot? Hence is it just an informational about the next boot time? Or does it mean it's a good idea to reboot soon? Is the install incomplete after getting this message? Why do some installs get this and others don't?